# Ancestor binding works only once in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, ancestor

I have a **Style** in my Window.Resources:

```
<Style x:Key="Header" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="80" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Tag}" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Polygon Name="P_up" Points="0,5 10,5, 5,0" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Margin="3" Visibility="Visible"/>
                        <Polygon Name="P_down" Points="0,0 10,0, 5,5" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Margin="3" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Header_Click"/>
    </Style>
```

When I set this style to my **ListView** (GridViewColumnHeader) like this:

```
<ListView Height="300" x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding PLCs}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Name="myNewText" Tag="test" Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Name="myNewText2" Tag="test2"  Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="test32"  Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The binding to the ancestors **Tag** works and the **Polygon**s are shown, but only for the last one of the **GridViewColumns**, the first two are staying blank. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Since the code is the same for all three columns I assumed it would provide me withe the same results for all three. I guess either the **Content** binding of the **Label** or the **TargetType** of the **Style** is not correct.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ContentTemplate` property:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
          <! -- ...place your stack panel here -->
         </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Doing so, you define a **template** for each column header. The template will instantiate the content for each column header independently.

If you use the `Content` property, you set the same stack panel as the content to all the column headers. This won't work - only the last one will win. The stack panel's parent will be automatically set to the last header. It's like:

```
header1.Content = your_stack_panel;
your_stack_panel.Parent = header1;

header2.Content = your_stack_panel;
your_stack_panel.Parent = header2;

header3.Content = your_stack_panel;
your_stack_panel.Parent = header3;
```

Comment: Additional information: By default every request for a ressource share the same instance (that's why there is only one `StackPanel`). You can avoid that by using [x:Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute). But i won't recommend that on a `Style`.

Comment: The polygons are visuals. You're trying to use the same instance of them multiple times and a visual can only have one parent. Templating generates an instance per usage.

Comment: @Andy, you indeed wanted to comment the OP's question, not my answer. It's not because of the polygons, anyway. Remove them from the OP's markup - the problem remains. Read my answer.